# ajax xml example from w3schools does not work

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax, dom

I was learning xml parsing in ajax in w3schools.com.
The example given there works but when I download it to my desktop it does not work.

The html elements are showing but the values from xml are not showing.

The filenames are abc.html and note.xml

Since the code is working in w3schools site I am assuming it is correct.

Comment: [Please, don't use w3schools. It's a horrible reference full of incorrect information that sometimes even leads to security holes.](http://w3fools.com)

Answer (score 0):

Browsers implement many security restrictions on local files. You cannot perform Ajax over `file://` URIs. You need to load the page over HTTP.

Comment: Look at your JavaScript console, what error messages are displayed? Look in your developer tool's Net tag, are the HTTP requests and responses as you expect?